# I am using Spyder 3.2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but the Python version is 2.7. How do I change it to Spyder Python3.6 version?

Tags: python3, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded the Anaconda from Anaconda's website for Python3.6 but it shows Python2.7 in Spyder. Actually I am doing an online course where instructor is using Python3.6 on Windows but I have Ubuntu18.04 LTS and I am unable to switch spyder Python2.7 to Python3.6.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu is still using Python 2.7.  But you can run Python 3 by using the command `python3`.  To get Spyder to use python3 follow the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592879/how-to-change-python-version-in-anaconda-spyder).  Use `which python3` to get the absolute path to python3.